# xstate pass event data into onDone from service

Tags: reactjs, xstate

I have xstate react script whereby a user fills in a form, and presses submit. On submit the xstate received a send("VALIDATE", {formData}) and that is run through a service that validates the form. On success the script transitions to the target: "success" and i need that final "success" state to call an external function which actually does the saving of the script.

I can get the data into the validator function, BUT, after the onDone, the subsequent success state doesn't appear to see the data.

How can I wire the data from the validating event to the success event??

```
 id: 'validator',
        initial: 'populating',
        context: {},
        states: {
        populating: {
            on: {
            VALIDATE: 'validating'
            }
        },
        validating: {
            invoke: {
            src: (context, data) => doValidate(data),
            onDone: {
                target: 'success',
                actions: assign({ data: "hello world"})
            },
            onError: 'failure'
            }
        },
        success: {
            invoke: {
                // I do see the hello world here, but what I want is the 'data' from the  doValidate(data)
                src: (ctx)=>{console.log("invoked success, what can I see here: ", ctx)}
            } 
        },
```

I'm triggering the validate via: `send("VALIDATE", formData)`

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly you want the event from the first service `onDone`to be available to the second service?
The easiest way would be to put the data on the `context` and access it in the other `state/service` and delete it afterward.

Or you can model your machine to `send` custom event to itself when the first
service is done.

```js
import { createMachine, assign, send, interpret } from "xstate";

const machine = createMachine({
  preserveActionOrder: true, //make sure actions are executed in order
  id: "validator",
  initial: "populating",
  context: {},
  states: {
    populating: {
      on: {
        VALIDATE: "validating"
      }
    },
    validating: {
      on: {
        // Listen to the event that fires when the first service is done
        FIRST_SERVICE_DONE: {
          target: "success"
        }
      },
      invoke: {
        src: (context, data) => Promise.resolve({ prop: "first service" }),
        onDone: {
          // target: 'success',
          actions: [
            assign({ data: "hello world" }),
            //instead of using target:'success' send a custom 
            //event that has access to the data from the service
            send((context, event) => {
              //event here has  event.data.prop === 'first service'
              console.log("send evt ", event);
              return {
                type: "FIRST_SERVICE_DONE",
                prop: event.data.prop
              };
            })
          ]
        },
        onError: "failure"
      }
    },
    success: {
      invoke: {
        src: (_ctx, evt) => {
          console.log("evt ", evt.prop);  //first service
        }
      }
    },
    failure: {}
  }
});

const service = interpret(machine);

service.start();

service.send({ type: "VALIDATE" });
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-kalam-mzh3v?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 1):

In Xstate the context is the extended state, so it doesn't seem like a good practice to use the context as a "machine memory". The extended state is used so that you don't have a potentially infinite number of states.

In case you need to preserve information that is sent by the event going to the state that invokes a Promise, you can add that information to the response. For example:

```js
export const myMachineServices = {
  myRequest: (context, event) =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({
          payload: 'some data',
        })
      }, 1000)
    }).then(res => ({
      ...res,
      event.data
    }))
    .catch(err => ({
      ...err,
      event.data
    })),
}
```